# Openlayers tiles not loading in PhoneGap app - jQuery Mobile conflict?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, openlayers

As part of my first PhoneGap app, I need to load up an OpenLayers map (ultimately using my own local custom tiles, but for the moment, I'm just testing with online ones, modding the standard OpenLayers examples).

But when I try to initialise the map in the iOS simulator, the tiles don't want to load, using either OpenStreetMap or alternatives. The map initialisation gets as far as placing the controls, and the copyright notice, but I keep getting the blue question-mark boxes instead of live tiles. Testing the map-loading code independently in a browser, it seems to function properly if I remove the jQuery Mobile references, but that doesn't seem to work if I tweak the file in Xcode, and besides that, it screws up my desired appearance and behaviour. Is this a known conflict and does anyone know a way around it?

Thanks in advance!

Giles

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobilecus-1.1.0.min.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sessionstorage.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/OpenLayers.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(function() { //ready
    // JQuery stuff trimmed out
    }); //end ready

    var map
    function init() {
       map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapview");
       map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
       var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 0.0 ,51.0).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection);
       var zoom=10;
       map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
       }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();"> 

<div data-role="page" id="page1" class="page">
     //html for first page (no map)
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="page2" class="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="fixedheader" data-position="fixed" >   
    <h1>Fixed header</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
            <div id="leftbar">
            <img src="images/leftbar.png">
        </div><!-- /leftbar -->
        <div id="mapview">
            //map appears here
        </div><!-- /mapview -->
        </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer"data-id="fixedfooter" data-position="fixed">
        <a id="ForwardButton">Forward</a><a id = "BackButton" href="#page2">Back</a>
    </div><!--/footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry - forget I spoke! Just discovered that I needed to add a reference to the map server domain to the "ExternalHosts" in Cordova.plist. Now the images seem to be loading okay.

Hopefully this will prove useful for someone else hitting the same problem, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - forget I spoke! Just discovered that I needed to add a reference to the map server domain to the "ExternalHosts" in Cordova.plist. Now the images seem to be loading okay.